# How to Concatenate SAS Multiple MACRO Variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

SO, I try to figure out how to concatenate SAS Macro

the below code works

```
%let VARIAVLE1 =XSCUGRAD;

%macro sqlloop(maxcnt);
 
 %do i=1 %to &maxcnt.;

   %if &i = 1 %then
         %do;

  %let t=12345;

  %let result =&&VARIAVLE&i;
  %put result=&result;

  %let result2=&result;
  %put result2=&result2;

    data dct&i;
    set dct;
    IF &result="A" THEN &result2="Not applicable";

RUN;
 
   %end;

%end;
%mend;
%sqlloop(maxcnt=1)

SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable RESULT resolves to XSCUGRAD
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable RESULT2 resolves to XSCUGRAD
```

then I am going to change

```
%let t=12345;

  %let result =&&VARIAVLE&i;
  %put result=&result;

  %let result2=&&result&t;
  %put result2=&result2;
```

I only changed this part, but this code did not work

```
 %let result2=&&result&t;
```

The error message is

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable RESULT resolves to XSCUGRAD
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable RESULT2 resolves to &result12345
NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "RESULT2".
1       &result12345
        -
        180
```

to create XSCUGRAD12345

How can/should I change???

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have a macro variable named RESULT12345?

Comment: @tom I just want to create variable/column XSCUGRAD12345

Comment: Please explain what SAS code you are trying to generate with your macro?

Comment: %LET is just another macro statement, it is not SAS statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to append a value to the of the value of a macro variable make sure you tell the macro processor where the name ends. You can do this with a period. Although I think for your situation you just have too many &'s for what you are trying to do since the & in &t should let the macro processor know where the name RESULT ends.

If your macro variables are like this:

```
%let result = XSCUGRAD;
%let t=12345;
```

Use the macro variables like this:

```
IF &result.="A" THEN &result.&t.="Not applicable";
```

or this:

```
IF &result="A" THEN &result&t="Not applicable";
```

To generate this statement.

```
IF XSCUGRAD="A" THEN XSCUGRAD12345="Not applicable";
```